# Discrepancy between characters remaining and length limit

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, character-limit

The real-time character counter on the [moderator nominations page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-10889873) claims I have 9 characters left. The non-real-time counter claims I have too many characters. PHP says that the non-real-time counter is correct, so why is the real-time counter so off?

[image: Nomination character count bug]

Comment: Are you *still* working on that thing? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Have been for the past 6 months ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great find and thanks for posting a screenshot that allowed me to recreate your input exactly.

The client javascript code is using `\n` line endings, while the server is using `\r\n`, causing this count discrepancy.

A fix that normalizes the endings before doing both client and server validation will be pushed in the next build, after rev 2012.6.6.2800.