# Miscalculated character count in tag wiki?

Tags: bug, tag-wiki-excerpt, character-limit

I was recently creating a tag wiki in Portuguese SE with the following text:

> Para perguntas sobre variações do português quando se desconhece para qual variação se aplica. Se a variação for pedida explicitamente (ex. português de Portugal), só a tag específica deverá ser usada (ex. [portugal](/questions/tagged/portugal)).
>
> For questions about variations of Portuguese in which the variation that it applies to is unknown. If the variation was explicitly mentioned (e.g. Brazillian Portuguese), then only the specific tag should be used (e.g. - [brasil](/questions/tagged/brasil)).

This excerpt is 459 characters long, and the live character counter correctly stated that I had 1 character left. However, the site refused it, claiming that I entered 461 characters.

[image: 461 characters?]

Indeed, removing one character from the text made it become accepted for peer review. On the other hand, this appears to be an inconsistent behaviour that should be addressed. I had first suspected that the back-end was miscalculating the character count of tag wikis with Western European characters, but then I figured that the server could be using "carriage-return + line feed" line endings, leading to the extra 2 characters. In fact, this had been [solved for nomination pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134693/282465) 3 years ago. Can it be that the same fix is missing for the case of tag wikis?

Comment: Not related, but just to point out that the tag syntax doesn't work in excerpts.

Comment: @animuson Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: You know certain unicode characters count as 2? And the SE sites __suck__ at handling unicode?

Comment: @UniformsForSale The byte count of the excerpt would have been more-less 470 in UTF-8, not 461. What are you suggesting with that comment?